Unable to create an object of type 'IdentityDataContext'
I'm encountering an issue while trying to update my database using Entity Framework Core in my .NET project. When I run the command:
dotnet ef database update --context IdentityDataContext

I receive the following error message:
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Unable to create an object of type 'IdentityDataContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

I have configured my IdentityDataContext to use PostgreSQL in my DependencyInjection class as shown below:
public static class DependencyInjection
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("LoginPostgres");

        services.AddDbContext<IdentityDataContext>(options => 
        {
            options.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
        });

        services.AddDbContext<LoginContext>(options => 
        {
            options.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
        });

        services.AddIdentity<Usuario, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDataContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddScoped<SignInManager<Usuario>, SignInManager<Usuario>>();

        services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

        services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepositorioGenerico<,>), typeof(RepositorioGenerico<,>));

        services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
        services.AddScoped<TokenService>();
        services.AddScoped<AutenticacaoService>();
        services.AddScoped<EmailService>();

        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        return services;
    } 
}

File IdentityDataContext:
using Login.Domain.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Login.Infrastructure.Data.Context
{
    public class IdentityDataContext : IdentityDbContext<Usuario>
    {
        public IdentityDataContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityDataContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
}

Does anyone have an idea of what might be causing this issue? How can I resolve it?
Thank you in advance for your help!
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'IdentityDataContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[Login.Infrastructure.Data.Context.IdentityDataContext]' while attempting to activate 'Login.Infrastructure.Data.Context.IdentityDataContext'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Unable to create an object of type 'IdentityDataContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Entity Framework Core cannot resolve the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions service when trying to activate IdentityDataContext.

Add the option --verbose at the end of your command and tell me what you got as an exception

I added it to the end of the question

Can you run it using Package Manager Console? (Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console). Ensure to reference the correct project from the dropdown (if you have many, the one with AddDbContext in Program.cs) and use the command Update-Database shortly. Tell me what you got.

I'm on Linux, I can't use VS

Use the command provided in my answer at your project's root directory.

A workaround can be done to fix that exception, by specifying --project and --startup-project options to Entity Framework Core CLI tools like this:
dotnet ef database update --verbose --project **YourProject**   --startup-project **YourStartupProject**


--project means which project contains the DbContext class

--startup-project means which project contains the database connection information and other information.


Edit
Similar question is answered here.

I looked at my own implementation of IdentityDbContext and my constructor just uses a plain DbContextOptions parameter, not a generic variant.
you could try changing this:
namespace Login.Infrastructure.Data.Context
{
    public class IdentityDataContext : IdentityDbContext<Usuario>
    {
        public IdentityDataContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityDataContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
}

to this and see if that helps
namespace Login.Infrastructure.Data.Context
{
    public class IdentityDataContext : IdentityDbContext<Usuario>
    {
        public IdentityDataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
}

